The class UserListDB is not in the limited set of classes for this realm (Parameter ‘T’)”. Error in MAUI .net8
I have a .NET MAUI project in which I want to implement MongoDB realm locally in iOS and Android.
My data model is composed of two classes:
public partial class UserListDB: IRealmObject
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public IList<UserListRoleDB> Roles { get; }
}

public partial class UserListRoleDB: IRealmObject
{ 
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}

We are using in .net MAUI to save data locally only we are not syncing to cloud
The code that follows sometimes generates an error:

The class UserListDB is not in the limited set of classes for this realm (Parameter ‘T’)

var realm = RealmService.GetRealm();

var data = realm.All<UserListDB>();

Could you please provide some suggestions?

Be aware that MongoDB Atlas Device sync is going away. It is depreciated with no replacement or future support. See the announcement here Atlas Device SDKs Deprecation so you should look for a different solution.

Thanks for your reply but we are using in .net MAUI to save data locally only we are not syncing to cloud ,

We can see this error sometimes in debug app but still not shown on release app .

There is some debate about the longevity of Realm (local). While it's not officially depreciated, my understanding is the team that worked on it has been re-purposed and there is no roadmap to show any continued support. More than likely it will be no longer be supported or updated so what it is now, it where it will stay. Perhaps more information will be available in the future but it may be a good time to look for another solution.
